# Are there magic commit words in Launchpad Code?

Tags: development, launchpad, bazaar

I know in a lot of source control tracking systems (Redmine, Trac, Jira) you can add magic words like `resolves #1234` in your commit message to have the bug updated to a certain status. Is there a feature like this with Launchpad - if so where, or what, is the list of magic keywords?

An example can be seen on Redmine's issue tracker page.

http://www.redmine.org/issues/6987 has two "Associated Revisions"

They're associated because the commit message has **Fixed: Wiki#find_page should not be case sensitive because page title uniqueness is not (#6987).** The combination of *Fixed* as a keyword and *#6987*, bug's unique ID, automatically updated the associated ticked to fixed.

Comment: You can tag the last revision if that's what you're looking for. Just use `bzr tag [tag]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/development/en/user-reference/bugs-help.html:

> When making a commit, metadata about bugs fixed by that change can be recorded by using the --fixes option. For each bug marked as fixed, an entry is included in the ‘bugs’ revision property stating `‘<url> <status>’`. (The only status value currently supported is fixed.)
>
> The `--fixes` option allows you to specify a bug tracker and a bug identifier rather than a full URL. This looks like:
>
> `bzr commit --fixes <tracker>:<id>`

For example,
`bzr commit --fixes lp:1234 -m "Fixes bug #1234` will mark Launchpad bug #1234 as fixed. The `"Fixes bug #1234"` message does not mark the bug as fixed but it will link to the bug report when browsing the commit history in Launchpad.
[image]